# Java ClassCastException when reflecting method

Tags: java

```
   public static <T> T invokeMethod(String className, String methodName, String jsonParams) throws Exception {
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(className);
        Object newInstance = aClass.newInstance();
        Method method = Arrays.stream(newInstance.getClass().getMethods())
                .filter(m -> m.getName().equals(methodName))
                .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(
                        String.format("can't find class: %s, method: %s ", className, methodName)));
        Type[] genericParameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
        Object result = null;
        Type genericParameterType = genericParameterTypes[0];

        // 1. work
        Object input = new Gson().fromJson(jsonParams, genericParameterType);
        result = method.invoke(newInstance, input);

        // 2. work
        result = method.invoke(newInstance, new Gson().fromJson(jsonParams, String.class));

        // 3. don't work， why ?
        // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
        method.invoke(newInstance, new Gson().fromJson(jsonParams, genericParameterType));

        return (T) result;
    }

    public String getName(String name) {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String result = invokeMethod("cn.com.demo.Test", "getName", "name");
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(result));
    }
```

three ways to reflect the method "getName",
but the third way throws the exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
why ?

Comment: In your 3rd attempt, the overloaded `fromJson` method you're using infers the type for its type parameter from the invocation context. Since `invoke` expects an `Object[]` for its second argument, that's the type that inferred. But that `fromJson` call returns a `String`. There's an implicit cast introduced that fails. Use `new Gson().<String>fromJson(...)` or call the method and assign it to a `String`, then pass the `String` to `invoke`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.